# how to return value from OnActionExecuting action filter

Tags: asp.net-web-api, asp.net-apicontroller

this is my API action filter,i want to be able to return the ccaccount obj

on good login result to the calling method

any idea how ?

thanks

```
   public class CAPILoginFilter : ActionFilterAttribute
    {
        public override void OnActionExecuting(HttpActionContext i_actionContext)
        {
            CRequestBase request = (CRequestBase)i_actionContext.ActionArguments["i_request"];

            CCAccount account = CAPILogin.AccountIDGetOBJ(request.UserName, request.Password);

            if(account == null)
            {
                throw new HttpResponseException(new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized));
            }
            else
            {
                //return account object to calling method here
            }

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

It is not possible to pass a value back from OnActionExecuting but you can set properties in the OnActionExecuting event that can be read by the method that caused it to fire.

In your OnActionExecuting event create a new property on request object.

```
context.Request.Properties["X"] = variableX;
```

This will be readable by the method that caused the event to fire like this

```
if (this.Request.Properties.ContainsKey("X"))
{
string x = this.Request.Properties["X"].ToString();

    // Use x here
}
```

Dave

Comment: this.Request in the ApiController refrernces a System.Net.Http.HttpRequestMessage object, NOT a System.Web.HttpRequest object.
httpRequestMessage is available to both Controller and Handler and its properties collection is writeable. 
They look the similar in the debug window so it is easy to confuse them, especially if you’re used to writing lots of non-API code (using the System.Web.HttpRequest object) Note that the HttpRequest object does not have a properties collection.